# Mongodb suddenly closed connection issue

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have started mongodb using mongod commad afterthat i opened mongo community compass then i have clicked collection names then suddenly mongodb connection closed and getting below error on my command prompt.
Why it is happening like this?How to resolve this issue? I have facing this issue very long time till now i am not able to find the solution.If anyone knows please help me to find solution.

Error:

```
2020-07-17T12:06:00.020+0530 E  STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (16) [1594967760:19816][9772:140727993851472], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __win_fs_rename, 125: C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle.set to C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle: file-rename: MoveFileExW: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
: Resource device Raw: [1594967760:19816][9772:140727993851472], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __win_fs_rename, 125: C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle.set to C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle: file-rename: MoveFileExW: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
: Resource device
2020-07-17T12:06:00.022+0530 E  STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (16) [1594967760:21812][9772:140727993851472], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __win_fs_remove, 81: C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle.set: file-remove: DeleteFileW: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
: Resource device Raw: [1594967760:21812][9772:140727993851472], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __win_fs_remove, 81: C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle.set: file-remove: DeleteFileW: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
: Resource device
2020-07-17T12:06:00.022+0530 E  STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (16) [1594967760:21812][9772:140727993851472], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __wt_turtle_update, 395: WiredTiger.turtle: fatal turtle file update error: Resource device Raw: [1594967760:21812][9772:140727993851472], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __wt_turtle_update, 395: WiredTiger.turtle: fatal turtle file update error: Resource device
2020-07-17T12:06:00.022+0530 E  STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (-31804) [1594967760:21812][9772:140727993851472], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __wt_panic, 490: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic Raw: [1594967760:21812][9772:140727993851472], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __wt_panic, 490: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2020-07-17T12:06:00.022+0530 F  -        [WTCheckpointThread] Fatal Assertion 50853 at src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_util.cpp 414
2020-07-17T12:06:00.022+0530 F  -        [WTCheckpointThread]

***aborting after fassert() failure


2020-07-17T12:06:00.096+0530 F  -        [WTCheckpointThread] Got signal: 22 (SIGABRT).
mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace_windows.cpp(246)                                                                       mongo::printStackTrace+0x43
mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\signal_handlers_synchronous.cpp(241)                                                              mongo::`anonymous namespace'::abruptQuit+0x81
ucrtbase.dll                                                                                                                       raise+0x1dd
ucrtbase.dll                                                                                                                       abort+0x31
mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(145)                                                                              mongo::fassertFailedWithLocation+0xd6
mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_util.cpp(414)                                                         mongo::`anonymous namespace'::mdb_handle_error_with_startup_suppression+0x2d1
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\support\err.c(263)                                                                __eventv+0x38d
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\support\err.c(312)                                                                __wt_err_func+0x2a
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\support\err.c(507)                                                                __wt_panic+0x40
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_turtle.c(395)                                                           __wt_turtle_update+0x38b
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_table.c(211)                                                            __wt_metadata_update+0x35b
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_ckpt.c(208)                                                             __ckpt_set+0xf1
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_ckpt.c(814)                                                             __wt_meta_ckptlist_set+0x3fa
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1605)                                                              __checkpoint_tree+0x1e0
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1738)                                                              __wt_checkpoint+0x94
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(911)                                                               __txn_checkpoint+0x70a
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1043)                                                              __txn_checkpoint_wrapper+0x189
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1101)                                                              __wt_txn_checkpoint+0x112
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\session\session_api.c(1962)                                                       __session_checkpoint+0x3bc
mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp(359)                                                    mongo::WiredTigerKVEngine::WiredTigerCheckpointThread::run+0x3f6
mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\background.cpp(154)                                                                               mongo::BackgroundJob::jobBody+0x145
mongod.exe    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(230)  std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<<lambda_e94772a372767cbd7bebbcdd24044cf3> >,std::default_delete<std::tuple<<lambda_e94772a372767cbd7bebbcdd24044cf3> > > > >::_Go+0x6d
mongod.exe    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(209)  std::_Pad::_Call_func+0x9
ucrtbase.dll                                                                                                                       beginthreadex+0x142
KERNEL32.DLL                                                                                                                       BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
2020-07-17T12:06:00.098+0530 F  CONTROL  [WTCheckpointThread] *** unhandled exception 0x0000000E at 0x00007FFDC788A799, terminating
2020-07-17T12:06:00.098+0530 F  CONTROL  [WTCheckpointThread] *** stack trace for unhandled exception:
2020-07-17T12:06:00.100+0530 I  -        [WTCheckpointThread] KERNELBASE.dll                                                                                                                       RaiseException+0x69
mongod.exe      ...\src\mongo\util\signal_handlers_synchronous.cpp(243)                                                              mongo::`anonymous namespace'::abruptQuit+0x9e
ucrtbase.dll                                                                                                                         raise+0x1dd
ucrtbase.dll                                                                                                                         abort+0x31
mongod.exe      ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(145)                                                                              mongo::fassertFailedWithLocation+0xd6
mongod.exe      ...\src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_util.cpp(414)                                                         mongo::`anonymous namespace'::mdb_handle_error_with_startup_suppression+0x2d1
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\support\err.c(263)                                                                __eventv+0x38d
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\support\err.c(312)                                                                __wt_err_func+0x2a
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\support\err.c(507)                                                                __wt_panic+0x40
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_turtle.c(395)                                                           __wt_turtle_update+0x38b
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_table.c(211)                                                            __wt_metadata_update+0x35b
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_ckpt.c(208)                                                             __ckpt_set+0xf1
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_ckpt.c(814)                                                             __wt_meta_ckptlist_set+0x3fa
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1605)                                                              __checkpoint_tree+0x1e0
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1738)                                                              __wt_checkpoint+0x94
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(911)                                                               __txn_checkpoint+0x70a
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1043)                                                              __txn_checkpoint_wrapper+0x189
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1101)                                                              __wt_txn_checkpoint+0x112
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\session\session_api.c(1962)                                                       __session_checkpoint+0x3bc
mongod.exe      ...\src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp(359)                                                    mongo::WiredTigerKVEngine::WiredTigerCheckpointThread::run+0x3f6
mongod.exe      ...\src\mongo\util\background.cpp(154)                                                                               mongo::BackgroundJob::jobBody+0x145
mongod.exe      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(230)  std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<<lambda_e94772a372767cbd7bebbcdd24044cf3> >,std::default_delete<std::tuple<<lambda_e94772a372767cbd7bebbcdd24044cf3> > > > >::_Go+0x6d
mongod.exe      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(209)  std::_Pad::_Call_func+0x9
ucrtbase.dll                                                                                                                         beginthreadex+0x142
KERNEL32.DLL                                                                                                                         BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
2020-07-17T12:06:00.101+0530 I  CONTROL  [WTCheckpointThread] failed to open minidump file C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.2020-07-17T06-36-00.mdmp : Access is denied.
2020-07-17T12:06:00.101+0530 F  CONTROL  [WTCheckpointThread] *** immediate exit due to unhandled exception
```

Comment: It looks like an issue with permissions. Have you tried to rightclick mongo.exe and run as Administrator?

Comment: @ippi:: Yes.Tried..But suddenly closed

Comment: @ippi: mongo.exe or mongod.exe?

Comment: mongod I suppose. But `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` Maybe you are having another instance that is running in the background that you need to close first. Or maybe your anti-virus is trying to access the files? Sorry, shooting in the dark.

Comment: @ippi: How to find another instance running in background? and how to stop it

Comment: @ippi:: And i have installed recently norton antivirus in my system